# Nested Query Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, a NextOfKin table and a Course table, the NextOfKin table has the following attributes:

```
StudentID 
ContactTelNo
```

And the course has this one (only showing relevant attributes):

```
CourseNo
```

I am trying to get an output where I show the studentID and contactTelNo for the next of kin of all students on course with courseNo equal to 1001.
This is the code I'm attempting to run

```
SELECT studentID, contactTelNo
FROM NextOfKin
WHERE courseNo =
(SELECT courseNo
FROM Course
WHERE courseNo = '1001')
```

I'm currently getting an error message that says "Unkown coloumn 'courseNo' in 'where clause'

where am I going wrong?

p.s I can only used a nested query and not a join

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM NextOfKin WHERE courseNo=...` — but the NextOfKin table doesn't have courseNo column.

Comment: (SELECT courseNo FROM Course WHERE courseNo = '1001') isn't it equal to 1001?

Comment: If the `Course` table has a `studentID` column, that attribute is also relevant. Even better if you have an `Enrolments` table of some kind. Somewhere you will have a table with both `studentID` and `CourseNo` columns, and we need to know more about that table before we can help you.

Comment: OP, please describe all the columns in each table and we will be able to help

Comment: Yes I have a table named Student that has  StudentID and CourseID attributes @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: @Toms, that's an odd place to put that information, since one student may have many courses. It means the Students table must repeat the record for the same student many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery needs to return student IDs, not course numbers, since that's what's in the `NextOfKin` table. And you need to use `IN` rather than `=` to check for membership in a set:

```
SELECT studentID, contactTelNo
FROM NextOfKin
WHERE studentID IN 
    (SELECT studentID
    FROM Course
    WHERE courseNo = '1001')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Course` also has a `StudentID` column, you want this:

```
SELECT NextOfKin.studentID, NextOfKin.contactTelNo
FROM NextOfKin
INNER JOIN Course ON Course.StudentID = NextOfKin.StudentID
WHERE Course.courseNo ='1001'
```

If `Course` does **NOT** have a `StudentID` column, you're looking at the wrong table. Somewhere you will have a table with columns for both `StudentID` and `CourseNo` values. It might be called something like `Enrollments` or `Registrations`.

Comment: I cannot use join would like to use a nested query

Comment: Why can't you use JOIN? That's the standard way to solve this issue. Nested queries are much less efficient and slower, as well as harder to write and maintain.

Comment: I am doing an assignment that requires me to use a nested query

Comment: In that case, I've given enough help already just pointing you to the correct table.